# how to implement sso for openshift

Tags: openshift

I'd like to implement kind of SSO for openshift, what I mean: from my webapp a user can open openshift console in a new window without giving his credentials. I've configured Basic Authentication Remote and it's working, can open new window and post username/password but it's looks that openshift is protected with crsf token. Thus not sure if it's possible at all. It seems that developing custom identity provider is not supported either. Any idea ?

PS I'm aware of Request Header Identity Provider but that solution requires my webapp to provide idp functionality (not even sure if it's feasible), also apache (we use nginx), a lot of issues for dev to install it all on a single computer due to port conflicts, valid ssl etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Best option will be to use oauth proxy. See if this helps in your case.
https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy

Comment: Thanks, will have a look for future development

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've implemented SSO using js postMessage to send user/token data and Basic Authentication Remote.